# Upgrade from postsharp 2.1.7 to 4.1.3 caused reference and target issue on MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, postsharp

I've got an issue with postharp 4 on MVC 5, after uninstall posharp 2.1 and removed from a C# mvc project and installed the postharp 4, cannot complie and build the project, and visual studio 2015 cannot find the targets of the postsharp 4.

> Unhandled exception (4.1.24.0, postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe, CLR
>   4.0.30319.393295, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly
>   'postsharp, version=2.1.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7'. [Version mismatch]============
>   PostSharp Assembly Loading Log ===================LOG: Finding the
>   assembly with binding identity 'postsharp, version=2.1.0.0,
>   culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7'.

But why does it want the postharp 2.1.0.0 version because it's not in the project anymore, I cleaned the references and all of the previous files, so only the version 4 is in the project.

I've got this error report in VS 2015: (a bit long...)

> Unhandled exception (4.1.24.0, postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe, CLR
>   4.0.30319.393295, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly
>   'postsharp, version=2.1.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7'. [Version mismatch]============
>   PostSharp Assembly Loading Log ===================LOG: Finding the
>   assembly with binding identity 'postsharp, version=2.1.0.0,
>   culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7'.LOG: Probing file
>   'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.1.24\bin.Release\PostSharp.dll' because it
>   is loaded in the AppDomain.LOG: Assembly 'PostSharp, Version=4.1.24.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7' does not match the
>   reference.LOG: Found file '"PROJECT
>   PLACE"\packages\PostSharp.4.1.24\lib\net35-client\PostSharp.dll' with
>   identity 'postsharp, version=4.1.24.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7, processorarchitecture=msil'.LOG:
>   Reference mismatch for '"PROJECT
>   PLACE"\packages\PostSharp.4.1.24\lib\net35-client\PostSharp.dll'
>   [VersionMismatch].LOG: Probing location
>   'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.1.24\bin.Release\PostSharp.exe' because
>   this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not
>   Found].LOG: Found file
>   'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.1.24\bin.Release\PostSharp.dll' with
>   identity 'postsharp, version=4.1.24.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7, processorarchitecture=msil'.LOG:
>   Reference mismatch for
>   'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.1.24\bin.Release\PostSharp.dll'
>   [VersionMismatch].LOG: Probing location
>   'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.1.24\bin.Release\PostSharp.winmd' because
>   this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not
>   Found].LOG: Probing location '"PROJECT PLACE"\bin\PostSharp.exe'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found].LOG: Found file '"PROJECT PLACE"\bin\PostSharp.dll' with
>   identity 'postsharp, version=4.1.24.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7, processorarchitecture=msil'.LOG:
>   Reference mismatch for '"PROJECT PLACE"\bin\PostSharp.dll'
>   [VersionMismatch].LOG: Probing location '"PROJECT
>   PLACE"\bin\PostSharp.winmd' because this directory was explicitly
>   added to the search path [File Not Found].LOG: Probing location
>   '"PROJECT PLACE"\obj\Debug\PostSharp.exe' because this directory was
>   explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].LOG: Probing
>   location '"PROJECT PLACE"\obj\Debug\PostSharp.dll' because this
>   directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not
>   Found].LOG: Probing location '"PROJECT
>   PLACE"\obj\Debug\PostSharp.winmd' because this directory was
>   explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].LOG: Probing
>   location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\PostSharp.exe'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found].LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\PostSharp.dll'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found].LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\PostSharp.winmd'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found].LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\PostSharp.exe'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found].LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\PostSharp.dll'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found].LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\PostSharp.winmd'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found].LOG: Looking in GAC for PostSharp, Version=2.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7,
>   processorArchitecture=x86.LOG: Looking in GAC for PostSharp,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7,
>   processorArchitecture=msil.LOG: Looking in GAC for PostSharp,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7.LOG:
>   The assembly 'postsharp, version=2.1.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7' was not
>   found.=============================================================== 
>   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.GetAssembly(IAssemblyName
>   assemblyName, BindingOptions bindingOptions, AssemblyLoadContext
>   context)   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyRefDeclaration.GetAssemblyEnvelope(BindingOptions
>   bindingOptions)   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.GetTypeDefinition(BindingOptions
>   bindingOptions)   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.GetTypeDefinition()   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.CompareExtensions.^G+gKPm9V(INamedType _0,
>   INamedType _1, BindingOptions _2)   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.CompareExtensions.DefinitionMatchesReference(INamedType
>   definition, INamedType reference, BindingOptions options)   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.^A9yFoe2uB3TC(ITypeSignature
>   _0, BindingOptions _1)   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.MatchesReference(ITypeSignature
>   reference)   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.CustomAttributeDeclarationCollection.Contains(IType
>   type)   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^SgrhoGlQ(AssemblyRefDeclaration
>   _0)   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^+GwnKh4ZYHu3()
>   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.Execute() 
>   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)   at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()   at
>   PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()   at
>   PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation
>   projectInvocation).

But the Public KeyToken is correct and the dll-s are there, just not the correct one. I've cleaned the packages folder to restore it from vs, but it only restores the bad DLL-s.
If anyone can help me, it would be great, because I would like to upgrade from postsharp on my mvc projects.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and click "Manage NuGet packages...". Search for Postsharp and reinstall from there.

If this does not work, try adding this to app.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="PostSharp" publicKeyToken="b13fd38b8f9c99d7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.24.0" newVersion="4.1.24.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```

Comment: I tried multiple times, the installation was finished, but it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: Search the entire solution for "b13fd38b8f9c99d7". What do you find?

Comment: That's the postsharp 4 PublicKeyToken... I knew that. And what about that?

Comment: Did it, just the problem is still the same. Are there any dependencies which can hold the old referencies from the postsharp 2.1?